# Fast and accurate computation of studentized external residuals in R

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, optimization, statistics

I want to compute the external studentized residuals of a dataset {x,y} of size *n* in R given the following constraints:

- (very) high precision
- high performance (avoiding loops where possible)
- R language (including RCPP)

The R code should be fast because it will be used extensively (10^9 times minimum) on multiple data sets with *n* in [10^3, 10^6]. This question is part of a larger work for estimating a custom statistic that requires the studentized residuals. The most computational part is the one presented here. Thus, solving this would dramatically improve the overall efficiency.

#### On the lm() regression

To gather the studentized external residuals, one typically runs `lm()` then `rstudent()`. The R function uses an aproach that avoid running *n* regressions for estimating the studentized residuals and that saves a lot of execution time. However, I prefer not to use `lm()` because I only need the residuals without all that fancy additional stuff that comes with it (thus saving some more execution time).

When trying to decipher the R source code for the external residuals in the `lm()` I found it somewhat obscur, as it seems to call sample code from other external files (an example is the `influence()` function). Thus, at this time I failed at collecting enough information to replicate the code section using the source code only.

#### Relevant topic(s) on Stack

The following relevant topic has been found in Stack: [How to compute Studentized Residuals in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485144/how-to-compute-studentized-residuals-in-python)

A R implementation of the Python procedure including a minimal example is given (corrected by @Stéphane Laurent, see answers):

```
n = 10    
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(n)
y = rnorm(n)
m = 2

mean_y = mean(y)
mean_x = mean(x)

diff_mean_sqr = (y - mean_y) %*% (y - mean_y)

beta_1 = ((y - mean_y) %*% (x - mean_x)) / diff_mean_sqr
beta_0 = mean_x - c(beta_1) * mean_y

x_hat = beta_0 + c(beta_1) * y

residuals = x - x_hat

h_ii = ((y - mean_y) ^ 2) / c(diff_mean_sqr) + (1 / n)
var_e = sqrt(vapply(1:n, function(i){
    fit <- lm.fit(cbind(1, y[-i]), x[-i])
    sum(fit$residuals^2)
    }, numeric(1)) / (n-m-1))
SE_regression = var_e * (sqrt(1 - h_ii))

studentized_residuals = residuals / SE_regression

reg = rstudent(lm(x ~ y))
res = cbind(reg, studentized_residuals)
```

Produce the following differences:

```
index    reg            studentized_residuals
1   -0,595911898846465  -0,581348373714385
2   0,116208945967327   0,116097011762269
3   -2,04779452591111   -1,61939642040734
4   2,26350621688535    1,71995630000724
5   0,603322309518977   0,588222428131761
6   -1,5460639774285    -1,33486217871738
7   0,367900050364855   0,364393996552621
8   1,14745971090533    1,05271762293388
9   0,823888320713653   0,786630743176311
10  -0,449839343257121  -0,443475039943641
```

#### Minimal example

The following R attemp has been tested using arbitrary datasets, just for illustration purposes.
It uses `lm()` / `rstudent()` and is way too slow for our practical application. The two parameters `n1` and `n2` correspond to the number of iterations and the size of the vector (denoted *n* in the above) respectively. To match our problem, we would typically pick `n1` in [10^6, 10^9] and `n2` in [10^3, 10^6] :

```
Stud = function(n1, n2){
  res = data.frame(matrix(vector(), n2, n1))

  for(i in 1 : n1){
    x = rnorm(n2)
    y = rnorm(n2)
    reg = lm(x ~ y)
    res[, i] = rstudent(reg)
  }
}
```

#### Update and additional (full) minimal example for benchmark:

Here we show a complete benchmark where various functions of Stack are tested against `lm()` in the objective of gathering the studentized externals residuals. For gathering these residuals we need to run 'n' regressions. Results are given after the code for 100 and 500 replications.

```
#Packages

install.packages("Rcpp")
library(Rcpp)
install.packages("RcppArmadillo")
library(RcppArmadillo)
install.packages("RcppEigen")
library(RcppEigen)
install.packages("stats")
library(stats)
install.packages("speedglm")
library(speedglm)
install.packages("Rfast")
library(Rfast)
install.packages("rbenchmark")
library(rbenchmark)

## start from SEXP, most conversions, longest code
src <- '
Rcpp::List fLmSEXP(SEXP Xs, SEXP ys) {
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix Xr(Xs);
    Rcpp::NumericVector yr(ys);
    int n = Xr.nrow(), k = Xr.ncol();
    arma::mat X(Xr.begin(), n, k, false);
    arma::colvec y(yr.begin(), yr.size(), false);
    int df = n - k;
    // fit model y ~ X, extract residuals
    arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);
    arma::colvec res  = y - X*coef;
    double s2 = std::inner_product(res.begin(), res.end(),
                                   res.begin(), 0.0)/df;
    // std.errors of coefficients
    arma::colvec sderr = arma::sqrt(s2 *
       arma::diagvec(arma::pinv(arma::trans(X)*X)));
    return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("coefficients")=coef,
                              Rcpp::Named("stderr")      =sderr,
                              Rcpp::Named("df")          =df,
                              Rcpp::Named("residuals")  =res);
}
'
cppFunction(code=src, depends="RcppArmadillo")

## start from Rcpp types are early RcppArmadillo examples did
src <- '
Rcpp::List fLmTwoCasts(Rcpp::NumericMatrix Xr, Rcpp::NumericVector yr) {
    int n = Xr.nrow(), k = Xr.ncol();
    arma::mat X(Xr.begin(), n, k, false);
    arma::colvec y(yr.begin(), yr.size(), false);
    int df = n - k;
    // fit model y ~ X, extract residuals
    arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);
    arma::colvec res  = y - X*coef;
    double s2 = std::inner_product(res.begin(), res.end(),
                                   res.begin(), 0.0)/df;
    // std.errors of coefficients
    arma::colvec sderr = arma::sqrt(s2 *
       arma::diagvec(arma::pinv(arma::trans(X)*X)));
    return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("coefficients")=coef,
                              Rcpp::Named("stderr")      =sderr,
                              Rcpp::Named("df")          =df,
                              Rcpp::Named("residuals")  =res);
}
'
cppFunction(code=src, depends="RcppArmadillo")

## start from Armadillo types
src <- '
Rcpp::List fLmOneCast(arma::mat X, arma::colvec y) {
    int df = X.n_rows - X.n_cols;
    // fit model y ~ X, extract residuals
    arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);
    arma::colvec res  = y - X*coef;
    double s2 = std::inner_product(res.begin(), res.end(),
                                   res.begin(), 0.0)/df;
    // std.errors of coefficients
    arma::colvec sderr = arma::sqrt(s2 *
       arma::diagvec(arma::pinv(arma::trans(X)*X)));
    return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("coefficients")=coef,
                              Rcpp::Named("stderr")      =sderr,
                              Rcpp::Named("df")          =df,
                              Rcpp::Named("residuals")  =res);
}
'
cppFunction(code=src, depends="RcppArmadillo")

## start from Armadillo types passed as constant references
src <- '
Rcpp::List fLmConstRef(const arma::mat & X, const arma::colvec & y) {
    int df = X.n_rows - X.n_cols;
    // fit model y ~ X, extract residuals
    arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);
    arma::colvec res  = y - X*coef;
    double s2 = std::inner_product(res.begin(), res.end(),
                                   res.begin(), 0.0)/df;
    // std.errors of coefficients
    arma::colvec sderr = arma::sqrt(s2 *
       arma::diagvec(arma::pinv(arma::trans(X)*X)));
    return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("coefficients")=coef,
                              Rcpp::Named("stderr")      =sderr,
                              Rcpp::Named("df")          =df,
                              Rcpp::Named("residuals")  =res);
}
'
cppFunction(code=src, depends="RcppArmadillo")

#Benchmark

data = benchmark("OneCast" = {
  n = 15
  set.seed(1)
  y = rnorm(n)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  m=2
  
  mean_data = mean(y)
  mean_x = mean(x)
  
  diff_mean_sqr = (y - mean_data) %*% (y - mean_data)
  
  beta_1 = ((y - mean_data) %*% (x - mean_x)) / diff_mean_sqr
  beta_0 = mean_x - c(beta_1) * mean_data
  
  x_hat = beta_0 + c(beta_1) * y
  
  residuals = x - x_hat
  
  h_ii = ((y - mean_data) ^ 2) / c(diff_mean_sqr) + (1 / n)
  
  var_e = sqrt(vapply(1:n, function(i){
    fit <- fLmOneCast(cbind(1, y[-i]), x[-i])
    sum(fit$residuals^2)
  }, numeric(1)) / (n-m-1))
  
  SE_regression = var_e * (sqrt(1 - h_ii))
  
  studentized_residuals = residuals / SE_regression
},
"TwoCast" = {
  n = 15
  set.seed(1)
  y = rnorm(n)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  m=2
  
  mean_data = mean(y)
  mean_x = mean(x)
  
  diff_mean_sqr = (y - mean_data) %*% (y - mean_data)
  
  beta_1 = ((y - mean_data) %*% (x - mean_x)) / diff_mean_sqr
  beta_0 = mean_x - c(beta_1) * mean_data
  
  x_hat = beta_0 + c(beta_1) * y
  
  residuals = x - x_hat
  
  h_ii = ((y - mean_data) ^ 2) / c(diff_mean_sqr) + (1 / n)
  
  var_e = sqrt(vapply(1:n, function(i){
    fit <- fLmTwoCasts(cbind(1, y[-i]), x[-i])
    sum(fit$residuals^2)
  }, numeric(1)) / (n-m-1))
  
  SE_regression = var_e * (sqrt(1 - h_ii))
  
  studentized_residuals = residuals / SE_regression
},
"Const" = {
  n = 15
  set.seed(1)
  y = rnorm(n)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  m=2
  
  mean_data = mean(y)
  mean_x = mean(x)
  
  diff_mean_sqr = (y - mean_data) %*% (y - mean_data)
  
  beta_1 = ((y - mean_data) %*% (x - mean_x)) / diff_mean_sqr
  beta_0 = mean_x - c(beta_1) * mean_data
  
  x_hat = beta_0 + c(beta_1) * y
  
  residuals = x - x_hat
  
  h_ii = ((y - mean_data) ^ 2) / c(diff_mean_sqr) + (1 / n)
  
  var_e = sqrt(vapply(1:n, function(i){
    fit <- fLmConstRef(cbind(1, y[-i]), x[-i])
    sum(fit$residuals^2)
  }, numeric(1)) / (n-m-1))
  
  SE_regression = var_e * (sqrt(1 - h_ii))
  
  studentized_residuals = residuals / SE_regression
},
"Sexp" = {
  n = 15
  set.seed(1)
  y = rnorm(n)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  m=2
  
  mean_data = mean(y)
  mean_x = mean(x)
  
  diff_mean_sqr = (y - mean_data) %*% (y - mean_data)
  
  beta_1 = ((y - mean_data) %*% (x - mean_x)) / diff_mean_sqr
  beta_0 = mean_x - c(beta_1) * mean_data
  
  x_hat = beta_0 + c(beta_1) * y
  
  residuals = x - x_hat
  
  h_ii = ((y - mean_data) ^ 2) / c(diff_mean_sqr) + (1 / n)
  
  var_e = sqrt(vapply(1:n, function(i){
    fit <- fLmSEXP(cbind(1, y[-i]), x[-i])
    sum(fit$residuals^2)
  }, numeric(1)) / (n-m-1))
  
  SE_regression = var_e * (sqrt(1 - h_ii))
  
  studentized_residuals = residuals / SE_regression
},
"Fast" = {
  n = 15
  set.seed(1)
  y = rnorm(n)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  m=2
  
  mean_data = mean(y)
  mean_x = mean(x)
  
  diff_mean_sqr = (y - mean_data) %*% (y - mean_data)
  
  beta_1 = ((y - mean_data) %*% (x - mean_x)) / diff_mean_sqr
  beta_0 = mean_x - c(beta_1) * mean_data
  
  x_hat = beta_0 + c(beta_1) * y
  
  residuals = x - x_hat
  
  h_ii = ((y - mean_data) ^ 2) / c(diff_mean_sqr) + (1 / n)
  
  var_e = sqrt(vapply(1:n, function(i){
    fit <- fastLm(x[-i] ~ y[-i])
    sum(fit$residuals^2)
  }, numeric(1)) / (n-m-1))
  
  SE_regression = var_e * (sqrt(1 - h_ii))
  
  studentized_residuals = residuals / SE_regression
},
"Speed" = {
  n = 15
  set.seed(1)
  y = rnorm(n)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  m=2
  
  mean_data = mean(y)
  mean_x = mean(x)
  
  diff_mean_sqr = (y - mean_data) %*% (y - mean_data)
  
  beta_1 = ((y - mean_data) %*% (x - mean_x)) / diff_mean_sqr
  beta_0 = mean_x - c(beta_1) * mean_data
  
  x_hat = beta_0 + c(beta_1) * y
  
  residuals = x - x_hat
  
  h_ii = ((y - mean_data) ^ 2) / c(diff_mean_sqr) + (1 / n)
  
  var_e = sqrt(vapply(1:n, function(i){
    fit <- speedlm(x[-i] ~ y[-i], fitted = T)
    sum((x[-i] - fit$fitted.values)^2)
  }, numeric(1)) / (n-m-1))
  
  SE_regression = var_e * (sqrt(1 - h_ii))
  
  studentized_residuals = residuals / SE_regression
},
".Fit" = {
  n = 15
  set.seed(1)
  y = rnorm(n)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  m=2
  
  mean_data = mean(y)
  mean_x = mean(x)
  
  diff_mean_sqr = (y - mean_data) %*% (y - mean_data)
  
  beta_1 = ((y - mean_data) %*% (x - mean_x)) / diff_mean_sqr
  beta_0 = mean_x - c(beta_1) * mean_data
  
  x_hat = beta_0 + c(beta_1) * y
  
  residuals = x - x_hat
  
  h_ii = ((y - mean_data) ^ 2) / c(diff_mean_sqr) + (1 / n)
  
  var_e = sqrt(vapply(1:n, function(i){
    fit <- lm.fit(cbind(1, y[-i]), x[-i])
    sum(fit$residuals^2)
  }, numeric(1)) / (n-m-1))
  
  SE_regression = var_e * (sqrt(1 - h_ii))
  
  studentized_residuals = residuals / SE_regression
},
"Fit" = {
  n = 15
  set.seed(1)
  y = rnorm(n)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  m=2
  
  mean_data = mean(y)
  mean_x = mean(x)
  
  diff_mean_sqr = (y - mean_data) %*% (y - mean_data)
  
  beta_1 = ((y - mean_data) %*% (x - mean_x)) / diff_mean_sqr
  beta_0 = mean_x - c(beta_1) * mean_data
  
  x_hat = beta_0 + c(beta_1) * y
  
  residuals = x - x_hat
  
  h_ii = ((y - mean_data) ^ 2) / c(diff_mean_sqr) + (1 / n)
  
  var_e = sqrt(vapply(1:n, function(i){
    fit <- lmfit(cbind(1, y[-i]), x[-i])
    sum(fit$residuals^2)
  }, numeric(1)) / (n-m-1))
  
  SE_regression = var_e * (sqrt(1 - h_ii))
  
  studentized_residuals = residuals / SE_regression
},
"Lm" = {
  n = 15
  set.seed(1)
  y = rnorm(n)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  m=2
  
  mean_data = mean(y)
  mean_x = mean(x)
  
  diff_mean_sqr = (y - mean_data) %*% (y - mean_data)
  
  beta_1 = ((y - mean_data) %*% (x - mean_x)) / diff_mean_sqr
  beta_0 = mean_x - c(beta_1) * mean_data
  
  x_hat = beta_0 + c(beta_1) * y
  
  residuals = x - x_hat
  
  h_ii = ((y - mean_data) ^ 2) / c(diff_mean_sqr) + (1 / n)
  
  var_e = sqrt(vapply(1:n, function(i){
    fit <- lm(x[-i] ~ y[-i])
    sum(fit$residuals^2)
  }, numeric(1)) / (n-m-1))
  
  SE_regression = var_e * (sqrt(1 - h_ii))
  
  studentized_residuals = residuals / SE_regression
},
"Basic" = {
  n = 15
  set.seed(1)
  y = rnorm(n)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  reg <- lm(x ~ y)
  reg_stud <- rstudent(reg)
},
replications = 500,
columns = c("test", "elapsed", "replications"))
```

**Results:**
On this single benchmark, the `rstudent(lm())` is **much** faster than everything else:

```
      test elapsed replications
7     .Fit   13.84          100
10   Basic    0.25          100
3    Const    7.37          100
5     Fast   99.84          100
8      Fit    7.06          100
9       Lm  105.25          100
1  OneCast    7.61          100
4     Sexp    7.66          100
6    Speed  184.76          100
2  TwoCast    7.17          100

7     .Fit   63.63          500
10   Basic    0.93          500
3    Const   34.44          500
5     Fast  438.95          500
8      Fit   31.11          500
9       Lm  471.37          500
1  OneCast   34.29          500
4     Sexp   33.48          500
6    Speed  794.73          500
2  TwoCast   33.51          500
```

**Interpretation**
It seems that R uses an analytical alternative that avoid using 'n' regressions, resulting in a much faster computation.
Thus, the question still remains: How to be competitive in regards to `rstudent(lm())`, and how to reverse-engeering the original source code (that is difficult to gather) ?

#### Final results

We compared the solutions of @Onyambu, @tester and @Stéphane Laurent. We found the solution of @Onyambu to be the fastest one for different vector sizes, while providing results exactly equal to those of `rstudent()`.

Comment: Relative to the Python original, did you intentionally swap `x` and `y` in your R port?

Comment: Do you have to do it iteratively? What's making this code slow is the loop, not the regression. Did you have a look at `.lm.fit` yet?

Comment: @tester I assume that's just for benchmarking, and OP actually wants to do bootstrapping or something.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat yes it was intended

Comment: @tester yes we did. and compared with other approaches such has the ones described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420185/fastlm-is-much-slower-than-lm
and tried all of these. But the point is that if you need to run 'n' regressions (iterate without observation 'i') then none of the proposed RCPP functions are efficient compared to the original rstudent().

Comment: @tester and to add some extra input it seems that using lmfit from Rfast is even faster:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420185/fastlm-is-much-slower-than-lm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT:

the edit is to indicate that a faster_rstudent function than the previously give was found:

```
fast_rstudent <-function(X, y, intercept = TRUE){
  mqr <- .Call(stats:::C_Cdqrls, cbind(intercept, X), y, tol, FALSE)
  res <- .Call(stats:::C_influence, mqr,  mqr$residuals, 1e-12)
  mqr$residuals/(res$sigma*sqrt(1-res$hat))
}
```

So far this function is very fast.

## Previous Answer

Since you are using R, you could use a `qr` decomposition to solve this. Your aim is to write a `rstudent` function that is faster than the inbuilt function by getting rid of the overhead function calls etc. That means that you should only use the necessary internal functions. Below is a quick way to do this:

```
my_rstudent <- function (X, y, intercept = TRUE) {
  X <- cbind(intercept, X)
  u <- .Call(stats:::C_Cdqrls, X, y, 1e-7, FALSE)
  d <- dim(X)
  n <- as.integer(d[1L])
  k <- as.integer(d[2L])
  df_res <- n - k
  
  z <- .Internal(diag(1, n, k))
  
  v <- .Fortran(.F_dqrqy, as.double(u$qr), n, k, as.double(u$qraux),
                z, k, qy = z)$qy
  
  h_ii <-.Internal(rowSums(v^2, n, k, FALSE))
  
  rstand <- u$residuals/sqrt(sum(u$residuals**2)/df_res)/sqrt(1-h_ii)
  
  rstand * sqrt((df_res - 1)/( df_res - rstand^2))
}
```

In a way this function misuses R by almost removing the overhead functions entirely. This assumes that what is being given to the function is correct.

---

Results:

```
n = 10    
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(n)
y = rnorm(n)

cbind(mine=my_rstudent(x, y), from_R=rstudent(lm(y~x)))
          mine      from_R
1   0.92113157  0.92113157
2   0.15753536  0.15753536
3  -1.69587949 -1.69587949
4  -3.59182456 -3.59182456
5   0.98274664  0.98274664
6  -0.85765961 -0.85765961
7  -0.07768369 -0.07768369
8   1.05874766  1.05874766
9   0.80181623  0.80181623
10  0.11418833  0.11418833
```

---

benchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(my_rstudent(x, y),rstudent(lm(y~x)),unit="relative", times = 100)
Unit: relative
                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   my_rstudent(x, y)  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000   100
 rstudent(lm(y ~ x)) 45.36667 37.20755 26.89753 24.29545 22.39587 11.31733   100
```

With a small dataset, the overhead functions quit slow down the computation of rstudent.

Relatively large dataset:

```
n = 1000    
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(n)
y = rnorm(n)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(my_rstudent(x, y),rstudent(lm(y~x)),unit="relative", times = 100)
Unit: relative
                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   my_rstudent(x, y) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
 rstudent(lm(y ~ x)) 8.530228 8.059269 7.700426 7.848123 7.616909 3.877305   100
```

---

huge dataset

```
n = 1000000    
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(n)
y = rnorm(n)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(my_rstudent(x, y),rstudent(lm(y~x)),unit="relative", times = 10)
Unit: relative
                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
   my_rstudent(x, y) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000    10
 rstudent(lm(y ~ x)) 1.510198 1.560989 1.486083 1.666609 1.603455 1.01154    10
```

---

Very huge dataset

```
n = 10000000    
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(n)
y = rnorm(n)
 microbenchmark::microbenchmark(my_rstudent(x, y),rstudent(lm(y~x)),unit="relative", times = 10)
Unit: relative
                expr      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
   my_rstudent(x, y) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000 1.000000 1.000000    10
 rstudent(lm(y ~ x)) 1.603652 1.603881 1.534455 1.58802 1.560724 1.305315    10

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(my_rstudent(x, y),rstudent(lm(y~x)), times = 10)
Unit: seconds
                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   my_rstudent(x, y) 1.584408 1.619822 1.727310 1.658917 1.757311 2.213203    10
 rstudent(lm(y ~ x)) 2.458445 2.619609 2.705212 2.696705 2.776588 2.949799    10
```

Comment: Thank you. We have two answers and will investigate which one is the fastest and post the results ni the main thread.

Comment: The initial proposed solution does work and provide the correct studentized residuals. However, the fastest solution (the one posted in the edit) does not work as it : ‘tol’ is not defined. Setting ‘tol = 1e-12’ gives another error, related to c_influence (this function takes 4 arguments, not 3). Trying to change the code to : res <- .Call(stats:::C_influence, mqr, mqr$residuals, weighted.residuals(lm(x~y)), 1e-12) does not provide the same residuals (compared to rstudent()).  Changing tol to machine precision should produce the exact same residuals as rstudent().

Comment: @Grasshoper. What 3xactly do you mean? From my end it gives correct results. And yes you could define the tol=.Maxhine$double

Answer (score 3):

One gets the same results by replacing your `var_e` with

```
var_e = vapply(1:n, function(i){
  sigma(lm(x[-i] ~ y[-i]))
}, numeric(1))
```

To get that efficiently, do not use `lm` but `lm.fit`:

```
var_e = sqrt(vapply(1:n, function(i){
  fit <- lm.fit(cbind(1, y[-i]), x[-i])
  sum(fit$residuals^2)
}, numeric(1)) / (n-m-1))
```

Comment: (i) replacing var_e with the proposed top estimate gives the exact same results. (ii) However, the proposed, more efficient, modifications using lm.fit does not produce the same output: [-0.44927705, 0.08488354, -1.40387608, 2.11661557, 0.45797412, -1.02415991, 0.26606776, 0.8275612, 0.59990871, -0.3239718].

Comment: @Grasshoper Sorry, that's because I (or rather you ;)) inverted `x` and `y`. I edit.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.Your solution solve the point (2) o fthe original request. However, I need to compare this to the original rstudent() function that also computes the studendized (external) residuals and make sure it is much faster.

Comment: @Grasshoper Use the `microbenchmark` package (or another benchmarking package). Not sure this will be faster because `rstudent` probably uses a similar way. Only benchmarks will tell us.

Comment: We are investigating it. I will post the result here when done and accept the answer if we have a "significant" decrease in the computing time.

Comment: after investigations, it happens that all the proposed solutions are slower than the original lm() and that is still a mystery. I'm updating the main topic.

Comment: @Grasshoper the answer I provided is much faster than the original `lm`

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution to your problem will be dropping all necessary overhead for the functions first, if that is not fast enough, try to convert the code to C++ and run it with Rccp. It is very likely that you'll be able to improve on my results, if you compute the residuals from `.lm.fit` using your own implementation, instead of using `lm.fit`, as I did.

I also checked, if there's a difference in the studentized residuals depending on the function you are going to use (`lm`, `lm.fit`, `.lm.fit`), it turns out that this is the case. However, the residuals from my function here are equal to those produced by `MASS::studres` for a regression of `y ~ x` with x having only one column.

Here's my code and a benchmark versus the fastest version from above called "Basic":

```
library(rbenchmark)
library(microbenchmark)
library(MASS)

set.seed(1)

x <- matrix(rnorm(500), ncol = 1)
y <- matrix(rnorm(500), ncol = 1)
myFunc <- function(x, y, n = 500){
  # tmp <- .lm.fit(x, y) # linear model fit
  object <- lm.fit(x = x, y = y)
  
  resid <- object$residuals
  hat <- lm.influence(object, do.coef = FALSE)$hat
  # hat <- hat[hat > 0] # remove checks
  # ok <- !(is.na(resid)) # remove checks
  # n.miss <- sum(!ok) # remove checks
  
  # resid <- resid[ok] # remove checks
  # n <- length(resid) 
  # p <- object$rank # equal to one
  p <- 1
  rdf <- n - 1
  
  studres <- resid
  
  stddev <- sqrt(sum(resid^2)/rdf)
  sr <- resid/(sqrt(1 - hat) * stddev)
  stdres <- sr
  studres <- sr/sqrt((n - p - sr^2)/(n - p - 1))
  
  studres <- naresid(object$na.action, studres)
  
  return(studres)
}

test1 <- stats::rstudent(lm(x ~ y)) # rstudent doesn't work with lm.fit
test2 <- MASS::studres(lm(x ~ y))
test3 <- MASS::studres(lm.fit(x, y))
test4 <- myFunc(x, y, n = 500)

> head(cbind(test1, test2, test3, test4))
       test1      test2       test3       test4
1 -0.6368094 -0.6368094  0.04696790  0.04696790
2  0.1493050  0.1493050 -0.27286396 -0.27286396
3 -0.8941217 -0.8941217 -1.15505676 -1.15505676
4  1.5598965  1.5598965  0.07729179  0.07729179
5  0.3440252  0.3440252  0.95155123  0.95155123
6 -0.7714317 -0.7714317  1.47600416  1.47600416

####################################

mbm <- microbenchmark("lm" = {rstudent(lm(y~x)) },
                      "MASS_lm" = {
                          MASS::studres(lm(y~x))
                      },
                      "MASS_lm.fit" = {
                        MASS::studres(lm.fit(x = x , y = y))
                      },
                      "myFunc" = {myFunc(x, y, n = 500)},
                      times = 100
)

> mbm
Unit: microseconds
        expr     min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
          lm 767.001 869.1510 1188.023 977.1505 1185.5010 8279.801   100
     MASS_lm 704.601 909.2000 1085.261 997.3515 1168.8505 2052.202   100
 MASS_lm.fit 168.001 195.0510  282.166 212.9510  254.1015 2912.201   100
      myFunc 147.901 168.8015  234.261 190.0010  249.7515 1193.701   100
```

Please note, that you'll have to specify `n` according to the length of the vector x or y.

Comment: Thank you. We have two answers and will investigate which one is the fastest and post the results.

Comment: We need to test your solution. The underlying question is : which of the two functions rstudent() or studres() do provide the most accurate residuals. This is yet another issue that should be investigated, but we are currently focused on computing the residuals that match the one of rstudent() (that we arbitrary chose as the most accurates)